# Prove that sum of velocity and squares of position is a constant using the function given

Tags: physics, constants

> An object moves along a line modeled by the x-axis. Its position (i.e. x-coordinate) after $t$ seconds is given by
> \begin{equation}
> x(t)=a\sin t + b \cos t
> \end{equation}
> where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants.

Looking at the information, I have a question in my mind: *how to prove that the sum of the velocity and squares of the position is always a constant?* I know that the velocity is $x'(t)=a \cos t - b \sin t$. I try to calculate the given value and use trig identities to see whether the value's a real number. Is my direction correct? If no, any other hints to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a typo: I think the problem refers to the sum of the squares of the position and speed.

If that is the case, the result is indeed true:

\begin{align*}
x^{2}(t) + v^{2}(t) & = (a\sin(t) + b\cos(t))^{2} + (a\cos(t) - b\sin(t))^{2}\\\\
& = a^{2}(\sin^{2}(t) + \cos^{2}(t)) + b^{2}(\cos^{2}(t) + \sin^{2}(t)) = a^{2} + b^{2}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Umm actually it's $x^2(t)+v(t)$...But anyways thanks for your effort!

Comment: Oh sorry, @Atila Correia. I am pretty much mistaken. You are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @patrickkk You can upvote my answer if you think it deserves.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer... Sorry :(

Comment: @carbontetrachloride you can also choose it.